# Android - How to differentiate between users who sign in and register from firebase signinintent builder?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I differentiate between users who sign in and register when using firebase signinintentbuilder? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java

A workaround for this is to store the user's UID when registering, but how can I store a UID if the user object is null when starting the signinintentbuilder?

This is the code that starts the signinintentbuilder : '

```
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
             // Start sign in/sign up activity
             startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
           );
        } else {
        // User is already signed in. Therefore, display

        // a welcome Toast
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }'
```

Highly appreciate anyone's advise right now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it: When the firebase UI flow finishes I "register" the user in the firebase DB and when the user logs out and presses for example the "google sign in" I check if the current uid is present in the firebase db. If it is the action that was performed was a "login" if not it was a "register"

Answer (score 0):

You can use onAuthStateChanged listener, it is always called on user signup or signin.

```
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getEmail());


                    presenter.saveLocationtoken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(),
                            user.getUid(),
                            user.getEmail(),
                            setRoleOnCreateUser(user));

                    userSignedInListener.updateNavHeader(firebaseAuth);
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // end of auth flow
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
//                    userSignedInListener.updateNavHeader(firebaseAuth);
                }
            }
```

It works even if you update your UID on every signin because firebase registration tokens might change for a certain user, after a certain period of time.